# Python & Inkscape: SVG-to-EMF conversion breaks down?

Tags: python, svg, matplotlib, vector-graphics, inkscape

I am trying to automatically convert an SVG graphic to EMF with Python, using Inkscape on the command line. My code is

```
from subprocess import call
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from numpy import linspace, sin

x = linspace(0,10,10)
y = sin(x)
plt.plot(x,y)
plt.savefig("source.svg")

for k in range(0,5):
    call(["C:\Program Files\Inkscape\inkscape.exe", "--file", "source.svg", "--export-emf", "result" + str(k) + ".emf" ]) 
    # this usually breaks down at k = 1 or 2
```

The "call" command works fine when called once. If I call it multiple times, e.g. on consecutive lines as shown above, Inkscape breaks down and I have to restart my python kernel and kill Inkscape via the Windows Task-Manager.

Any ideas why that might be?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried the `--without-gui` option of inkscape? Maybe it doesn't get turned on automatically.

Comment: On my Win 7 x64 system this script works without any problem.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this problem on Windows 8.1 64bit, Inkscape 0.91, python 2.7. Everything works as expected.

Comment: I found that it seems to depend on where the files are stored. If I run the script locally on my desktop, it works fine. If it is place on a NAS drive, it fails.?